# Java Object to JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an Object array which is a list of argument values a function could take. This could be any complex object.

I am trying to build a json out of the Object array using gson as below:

```
private JsonArray createArgsJsonArray(Object... argVals) {
    JsonArray argsArray = new JsonArray();
    Arrays.stream(argVals).forEach(arg -> argsArray.add(gson.toJson(arg)));
    return argsArray;
}
```

1. This treats all the arg values as String.
2. It escapes the String args

   ```
   "args":["\"STRING\"","1251996697","85"]
   ```

I prefer the following output:

```
   "args":["STRING",1251996697,85]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using gson?

I used `org.json`, I was able to achieve the desired result, but it does not work for complex objects.

### EDIT:

I applied the solution provided by @Michał Ziober, but now how do I get back the object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object strObj = "'";
JsonObject fnObj = new JsonObject();
JsonObject fnObj2 = new JsonObject();
fnObj.add("response", gson.toJsonTree(strObj));
fnObj2.addProperty("response", gson.toJson(strObj));

System.out.println(gson.fromJson(fnObj.toString(), 
Object.class)); --> prints {response='}   //Not what I want!
System.out.println(gson.fromJson(fnObj2.toString(), 
Object.class)); --> prints {response="\u0027"}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to call the toString() method of the object?

Comment: yes, you are right! I print it using toString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `toJsonTree` method:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonApp app = new GsonApp();
    System.out.println(app.createArgsJsonArray("text", 1, 12.2D));
    System.out.println(app.createArgsJsonArray(new Date(), new A(), new String[] {"A", "B"}));
  }

  private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

  private JsonArray createArgsJsonArray(Object... argVals) {
    JsonArray argsArray = new JsonArray();

    for (Object arg : argVals) {
      argsArray.add(gson.toJsonTree(arg));
    }

    return argsArray;
  }
}

class A {
  private int id = 12;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
["text",1,12.2]
["Sep 19, 2019 3:25:20 PM",{"id":12},["A","B"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but now I don't how to get back the object? I have added details in the EDIT section of my question.

Comment: @user2761431, I'm not sure what do you want to do. You want to create a `JSON Array` with some different elements and after that you want to deserialise it back to `Object[]`?

Comment: Ziober yes, I need to serialize and de-serialize.

Comment: @user2761431, if you have an object what is the point to serialise and deserialise it back? In your example, you want to serialise apostrophe and what do you expect after deserialisation? Please, create a new question, with working example what you get right now and what do you expect to receive.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setPrettyPrinting` with `DisableHtml` escaping.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
 JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
 JsonElement je = jp.parse(jsonArray.toString());
 System.out.println( gson.toJson(je));
```

Comment: I will not be able to build the JsonArray in the desired format? I have to process it post building the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to end up with a String, just do:

```
private String createArgsJsonArray(Object... argVals) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(argVals);
}
```

If you wish to collect it back and alter just do:

```
Object[] o = new Gson().fromJson(argValsStr, Object[].class);
```